# NDSolve output where the stepsize becomes zero

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

When solving ODE using NDSolve, one might encounter error message when the effective step size becomes zero at $r=r_c$. Is there a way to get $r_c$ as an output instead of error message?

Comment: `sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2}]; (y["Domain"] /. First@sol)[[1, 2]]`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you explain in more detail? For example, how to generalize it to higher dimensional ODEs?

Comment: Example? Please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MichaelE2 It seems the obvious way works. Thanks!